# How to check whether an object has certain method/property?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, reflection, properties

Using dynamic pattern perhaps? You can call any method/property using the dynamic keyword, right? How to check whether the method exist before calling myDynamicObject.DoStuff(), for example?

Comment: What is the type of *myDynamicObject*? Is it a class derived from `DynamicObject`?

Comment: something declared with the dynamic keyword

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You could write something like that :

```
public static bool HasMethod(this object objectToCheck, string methodName)
{
    var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
    return type.GetMethod(methodName) != null;
}
```

Edit : you can even do an extension method and use it like this

```
myObject.HasMethod("SomeMethod");
```

Comment: GetType() will return the runtime type? (i.e. not object?)

Comment: yes, GetType() returns the running type whereas typeof() would return object.

Comment: According to the docs GetType() will return "The exact runtime type of the current instance".

Comment: Also, the extension method would need to be static.

Comment: I prefer to write: 
objectToCheck.GetType().GetMethod(methodName) != null

Comment: Has explained in the comment after, you can use the new type dynamic : dynamic dynObj = myObject; dynObj.SomeMethod();

Comment: Extension methods don't work for `System.__COMObject`s for me; solution for me is to remove the `this` and use the method without the sugar.

Comment: I used this to make HasProperty() and HasEvent() methods.  Will only find them if Public (and) has {get; set;}.   Works well though...

Comment: the type.GetMethod will throw an exception "ambiguous method" if there is overloads for this method in the targeted class! Beware.

Comment: If you create an extension method on the object type it'll hang off every object that is in scope.  That can get noisy.  I needed this sort of thing in my test project so put it in a restrictive namespace to hide it from all but the one test class.

Comment: what about property?

Answer (score 107):

via Reflection

```
 var property = object.GetType().GetProperty("YourProperty")
 property.SetValue(object,some_value,null);
```

Similar is for methods

Comment: Nice. You could also do the GetMethod in a loop to get the appropriate defined property.

Comment: Useful for looping through linked lists of UI controls and their Parents

Comment: In `GetType()` there is method like `GetProperties()`. It is returning array of `PropertyInfo`. But how can I use `GetProperties()` method?

Answer (score 55):

It is an old question, but I just ran into it.
`Type.GetMethod(string name)` will throw an AmbiguousMatchException if there is more than one method with that name, so we better handle that case

```
public static bool HasMethod(this object objectToCheck, string methodName)
{
    try
    {
        var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
        return type.GetMethod(methodName) != null;
    }
    catch(AmbiguousMatchException)
    {
        // ambiguous means there is more than one result,
        // which means: a method with that name does exist
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

Wouldn't it be better to not use any dynamic types for this, and let your class implement an interface.
Then, you can check at runtime wether an object implements that interface, and thus, has the expected method (or property).

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
   void Somemethod();
}


IMyInterface x = anyObject as IMyInterface;
if( x != null )
{
   x.Somemethod();
}
```

I think this is the only correct way.

The thing you're referring to is duck-typing, which is useful in scenarios where you already know that the object has the method, but the compiler cannot check for that.
This is useful in COM interop scenarios for instance. (check [this](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/42590) article)

If you want to combine duck-typing with reflection for instance, then I think you're missing the goal of duck-typing.

Comment: what if the object can be an object provided by the .NET framework, and I cannot declare it to implement anything?

Comment: What's the problem ?  You can check whether the 'object' is such an object, provided by the .NET framework just in the same way

Comment: for example, you want to check whether there is an "Add" method in an object. ANd the object can be a List<int>, or some other class that's not an IEnumerable

Comment: So, you have absolutely no idea which class you're using when using a .NET base class ?  Can you show some real-life example code ?  I think it smells.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at scripting an Adobe product with COM. The same function call can return entirely different COM objects, and by (Adobe's) design, their only common ancestor is object. Also: this is a commonplace pattern in pretty much any modern dynamic scripting language (Python, Javascript, VB script, PHP, Lua... I could go on and on). It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: It is a smell but it was created by microsoft. Look at WebControls such as Button, LinkButton, etc. They both implement OnClientClick property but, say,  ListControl and Panel do not. OnClientClick is not defined in an interface so reflection is the only option.

Comment: Theatrically* this is the right way for high quality code
*`...it would be easy
to do if the test were hidden in a routine and hard to do if it were a complicated
test hard-coded throughout the program.
` - Code Complete by Steve McConnell

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `AmbiguousMatchException`, I would rather say

```
objectToCheck.GetType().GetMethods().Count(m => m.Name == method) > 0
```