# How to safely check if a dynamic object has a field or not

Tags: c#

I'm looping through a property on a dynamic object looking for a field, except I can't figure out how to safely evaluate if it exists or not without throwing an exception.

```
        foreach (dynamic item in routes_list["mychoices"])
        {
            // these fields may or may not exist
           int strProductId = item["selectedProductId"];
           string strProductId = item["selectedProductCode"];
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic, How to test if a property is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/dynamic-how-to-test-if-a-property-is-available)

Comment: why are  you trying to use  foreach (dynamic item ant to just var

Comment: This is the best answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839598/how-to-detect-if-a-property-exists-on-a-dynamic-object-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check whether an object has certain method/property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114469/how-to-check-whether-an-object-has-certain-method-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround your dynamic variable with a try catch, nothing else is the better way in makking it safe.

```
try
{
    dynamic testData = ReturnDynamic();
    var name = testData.Name;
    // do more stuff
}
catch (RuntimeBinderException)
{
    //  MyProperty doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Oh no! You try to use Exceptions in logic, while just need to check your property in a list (casting to ExpandoObject or using reflection). Instead of that you call a nuclear bomb - causes and the handle exception.

Answer (score 5):

using reflection is better than try-catch, so this is the function i use :

```
public static bool doesPropertyExist(dynamic obj, string property)
{
    return ((Type)obj.GetType()).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.Equals(property)).Any();
}
```

then..

```
if (doesPropertyExist(myDynamicObject, "myProperty")){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ((Type)obj.GetType()).GetProperties().Any(p => p.Name.Equals(property));

Comment: ((Type)obj.GetType()).GetProperties() doesn't get me any properties even though I can see there are properties

Answer (score 2):

This is gonna be simple. Set a condition which checks the value is null or empty. If the value is present, then assign the value to the respective datatype.

```
foreach (dynamic item in routes_list["mychoices"])
        {
            // these fields may or may not exist

            if (item["selectedProductId"] != "")
            {
                int strProductId = item["selectedProductId"];
            }

            if (item["selectedProductCode"] != null && item["selectedProductCode"] != "")
            {
                string strProductId = item["selectedProductCode"];
            }
        }
```

Comment: You check `selectedProductId` in both `if` statements.

Comment: the property itself is possibly missing from the dynamic object , not the value - so standard null check throws invocation exception - try{}catch{} seems to do the job though